# Transactional Email - Magento 1.9 Email Order Notification

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I recently purchased some templates from theme forest.
https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-custom-email-templates-pro/19175962?s_rank=2

installed on the server and all is working great, I noticed in the code the images (thumbnails) were not showing up.

The code looks like this here,

```
foreach ($wa_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
$vars = get_object_vars ($value);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($value->getOrder()->getStoreId())
            ->load($value->getProductId());
$item = array(
  'url' => $_product->getProductUrl(),
  'imgUrl' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                   ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()),
  'name' => $value->getName(),
  'sku' => $vars['_data']['sku'],
  'description' => $vars['_data']['description'],
  'number' => $vars ['_data']['product_id'],
  'qty' => intval($vars['_data']['qty_ordered']),
  'price' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']['base_price']),
  'total' => $wa_data['symbol'] . ' ' . intval($vars['_data']
['base_row_total']),
);
 $wa_data['items'][$key] = $item;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is an issue here,

```
'imgUrl' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
               ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()),
```

on the image in the code it looks like this here,

```
<a href="<?php echo $_item['url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $_item['imgUrl'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $_item['name'] ?>" />
```

Can you please help me get these thumbnails working. I'm using Magento 1.9.3

Any help understanding what is would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In this case is better to use `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')` instead of `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')`.

But this code is working
`Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail())`

You should check is product has thumbnail for store in admin panel.

Comment: I'm having a problem showing a configurable product with this code

Comment: Can anyone give me some help on how to show the configurable product as well. this only works on single product images.

Comment: I've checked this code with configurable products and it worked fine. $_product->getThumbnail() will get product image that is marked as "Thumbnail" for product. Please make sure that product from your list really have "thumbnail" images.
If you want to get base image you can do this $_product->getImageUrl();

Comment: If you create an order for bundle product, single product and configurable product. you'll see that the configurable product is showing both images. so if I ordered the black, in the email the black and silver image show up. I'm testing configurable, bundle and single products in one order. there is some issues still